# Getting element data from xml file?

Tags: python, xml, xmldom

I am trying to get the text data of an element tag in XML.

My XML file is:

```xml
<root>

<subroot>

<child1/>
<child2/>
Data of subroot

</subroot>

<root>
```

I wrote the following python code to get the data:

```
import xml.dom.minidom as m

dom.m.parse("myXMLfile.xml")
var=getElementsByTagName("subroot")[0]
var_data=var.childNodes[0].data                # to get the data
```

But this code is producing error : `childNodes is not defined for element "var"`

How can I get data of an element that has multiple empty tags within it?

Please suggest what changes do I need to make into my program.

Answer (score 0):

This will get all the element data (including multi line data):

```
import xml.dom.minidom as m

dom = m.parse("myXMLfile.xml")
var = dom.getElementsByTagName('subroot')
elem_data = "".join(var_data.nodeValue.lstrip() for var_data in var[0].childNodes if var_data.nodeType == var_data.TEXT_NODE)

print elem_data    ## Data of subroot
```

The `.lstrip()` is used to remove extra white spaces in `elem_data`, which was as a result of the way the xml file was formatted. If you want the white spaces as it appears within the `<subroot>` element, then remove `.lstrip()`